# Configure Maven so that it uses jars for compilation but excludes them while bundling into war file

Tags: maven

I got a requirement to customize our projects using Maven. We have 3 projects based on Spring & Hibernate. Hence, there are repeated jars in each WAR file while building, which increases size unnecessarily while deployment.

So we have decided to keep all jar dependencies into one project called "CommonJars" and other existing projects will use them. For deployment, we want to generate TAR/ZIP file of "CommonJars" (while deploying it should be extracted in folder, most probably lib folder of Tomcat as it is common to the projects deployed in webapps folder) and other WAR file without jars. So that we can reduce the size of WAR files of 3 projects.

Can somebody suggest me on how we can achieve this? As I am new to Maven, I am unable to find proper solution for this.

Comment: Since you are new to Maven, please do this the right way. What you have decided is definitely NOT a good practice and should NEVER be done. You are going to get in trouble in the near future with this. A war file should include all its dependencies. If the war is too big, you should try to minimize the number of dependencies: post your POM and we can maybe help with that. 1. adding manual dependencies in your Tomcat will break once one of your projects will need to upgrade and not the others; 2. if you change servers from Tomcat to some other, there's a good chance everything will break.

Comment: Yes Tunaki. I am aware of this issue. As I am working on small internal project and that will not be migrated. So we are decided to go with this approach.
Do you have any better suggestion to decrease size of WAR files..?

Comment: As I said in my comment, reduce the size of the war by removing unnecessary dependencies (not by adding them to your server dependencies). This is the only way to go. And if everything is necessary, then there is nothing you can do, unfortunately (well you can go with the answer you got, it will work but beware of the future consequences).

Answer (score 4):

I do not agree with your approach but to solve your maven issue, you need to include a 'scope' in your maven dependency.

Example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The [Maven Scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) 'provided' will allow you to compile your projects but maven will not include them in your war.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I am doing in same way. With this I could generate WAR file without jars.
In addition to this, I want to generate TAR/ZIP file also which includes all the jars and needs to be deployed.

Can you please suggest if there is way to do that... ?

Comment: Your next question falls outside of the scope of this original question. But you can certainly make it happen. One way would be by generating an ANT file and calling it from your maven.